# Best practise to route Dashbord Post and Post

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, routes

I have two layout:

- Dashboard (Where logged user can Add/EDIT/Delete new Post)
- Public view (where anybody can read Posts)

I would like to get urls like: 
**dashboard_post_path** and
**post_path**

but I don't want to have two different controllers (eg. **PostController** and **DashboardPostController**), because I want to share the same code and switch only the layout ('**dashboard**' layout OR '**default**' layout).
I've tried this

```
namespace :dashboard do 
      resources :posts
    end
```

but I get

[image]

because it looks for **dashboard/posts#index** controller

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_post, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_filter :authenticate_user!, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy, :new]
  layout 'dashboard'

 //...
end
```

Answer (score 2):

You can write conditional layout like below

Conditional Layouts

Layouts specified at the controller level support the :only and :except options. These options take either a method name, or an array of method names, corresponding to method names within the controller:

```
  class EventsController < ApplicationController
    layout :resolve_layout

    def resolve_layout
      case action_name
      when "show"
          "post_layout"
      when "index"
          "dashboard_layout"
      else
         "default_layout"
      end  
    end
end
```

Are you looking something like this?

Comment: Ok, but I could detect if the user is on "dashboard" or default?

Comment: I did not get that can you explain in detail.

Comment: Look the code that I've posted on the question. In PostController how I can detect if I'm in the "dashboard" case or not?